# Hindi text verify which is inside button + selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

I'm new in the selenium and I want to verify the Hindi text which is inside button. I can get the Hindi text by using gettext() method. but I don't know how to verify that text. can anybody help me out for this.

[image]

Comment: please add the code you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
String hindiString = new String("अग्रसर रहें");
Boolean textIsEqual = hindiString.contentEquals(textFromSeleniumWebElement); // this should verify.
        
//You may also verify the same by checking the byteArray content of both the elements
byte[] hindiBytes = hindiString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```